# Get rid of this button in KDE4?

Tags: kde4

Looks like mandatory, I run plasma-desktop, there's always a button on the right corner,

is there anyway to remove that? It wasn't an removable "widget"

[image]

Comment: You're referring to the *cashew*, right?  There are [some hacks](http://software.opensuse.org/search?q=cashew&baseproject=openSUSE%3A12.1&lang=en&include_home=true&exclude_debug=true) you could try... ([more info here](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-kde/2012-02/msg00109.html))